# MongoDB aggregation pipeline analogue for SQL query with substr operation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

MongoDB equivalent for

```
SELECT state, SUM(pop) AS totalPop
FROM zipcodes
GROUP BY state
HAVING totalPop >= (10*1000*1000)
```

is

```
db.zipcodes.aggregate( [
   { $group: { _id: "$state", totalPop: { $sum: "$pop" } } },
   { $match: { totalPop: { $gte: 10*1000*1000 } } }
] )
```

How can I get MongoDB equivalent for SQL query where `substr` operation is involved

```
SELECT substr(state,0,3), SUM(pop) AS totalPop
FROM zipcodes
GROUP BY substr(state,0,3)
HAVING totalPop >= (10*1000*1000)
```

Comment: Provide structure of your document.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`$substr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) String aggregation operator on `status` field and [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage at the end of aggregation pipeline to get desired output

```
db.zipcodes.aggregate([
  { $group: { "_id": { $substr: [ "$state", 0, 3 ] }, "totalPop": { $sum: "$pop" } } },
  { $match: { "totalPop": { $gte: 10*1000*1000 } } },
  { $project: { "state": "$_id", "totalPop": 1, "_id": 0  } }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It works. However I am facing a different challenge now. my data is stored as epoch 1470421645 which includes hours , minutes & seconds as well. However I want only the date information which is 1470355200. So  1470421645  = 2016/08/05 18:27:25 GMT and 1470355200 = 2016/08/05 00:00:00 GMT. Appreciate if you can provide some guidance

Comment: @SourabhJain Edit your question here with your new request or create another question about it. If you gonna edit this question then provide exact structure of your documents in MongoDB collection.